# can't change var inside conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with a debounce :

js:

```
var startClick = true
var finishClick = false

$(document).ready(function(){
if(startClick == true) {
    $("#enter").click(function(){
        finishClick = true;
        startClick = false;
        $("#start").animate({bottom: "+=1000px"}, "slow");
        $("#finish").animate({bottom: "+=1000px"}, "slow");
    }); 
};

if(finishClick == true) {
    $("#back").click(function(){
        finishClick = false;
        startClick = true;
        $("#back").animate({top: "+=5px"}, "200");
        $("#start").delay("400").animate({bottom: "-=1000px"}, "slow");
        $("#finish").delay("400").animate({bottom: "-=1000px"}, "slow");
        $("#back").delay("400").animate({top: "-=5px"}, "0");
    }); 
};
});
```

I click on the start button and the page slides up like expected, but when I click on the finish button nothing happens, as if finishClick isn't set to true, because when I set finishClick to true at the start of the script both buttons will work normally, back and forth.

Comment: document ready will be called only once.

Comment: Change the order. Do:     `$("#back").click(function(){ if(finishClick == true) { ...` So bind the event listener first, and in that make the condition.

Comment: you need onclick and then you check for finishClick... based on that you can update your var

Comment: when document ready was called initially your `finishClick` was false. So the function you have written using `finishClick` didn't parse at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move the `if` condition inside click handler

```
var startClick = true
var finishClick = false

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#enter").click(function() {
        if (startClick == true) {
            finishClick = true;
            startClick = false;
            $("#start").animate({ bottom: "+=1000px" }, "slow");
            $("#finish").animate({ bottom: "+=1000px"}, "slow");
        };
    });

    $("#back").click(function() {
        if (finishClick == true) {
            finishClick = false;
            startClick = true;
            $("#back").animate({top: "+=5px" }, "200");
            $("#start").delay("400").animate({ bottom: "-=1000px"}, "slow");
            $("#finish").delay("400").animate({bottom: "-=1000px"}, "slow");
            $("#back").delay("400").animate({top: "-=5px"}, "0");
        };
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(startClick == true) {
$("#enter").click(function(){
    finishClick = true;
    startClick = false;
    $("#start").animate({bottom: "+=1000px"}, "slow");
    $("#finish").animate({bottom: "+=1000px"}, "slow");
});
```

put this code out of document ready